Combining derivatives when taken with respect to the same variable
Is there a way to collect derivatives w.r.t. the same symbol in a sum?
There are several questions that go around this point, but I haven't found an answer for the simple situation:
from sympy import *
x,y,z,t = symbols('x y z t')
expr = z * (Derivative(x,t) + Derivative(y,t))
expr    

'z*(Derivative(x, t) + Derivative(y, t))'

expr.simplify(doit=False)

'z*(Derivative(x, t) + Derivative(y, t))'

I would expect to get
'z*Derivative(x+y, t)'

I have tried using the replace function to substitute derivation with multiplication, but going back is not really working due to the factor zbeing reorganized, or simplification functions failing to handle non-commutative symbols.

(ideally) use a recursion: detect the Derivative object  with term.is_Derivate,  use term.args to decomposite it in a tuple of the form f(of something), *tuples_var_label_and_order . Keep track of the coefficient of the derivative and then collect together per depth and tuples_var_label_and_order

Thanks, that's still a little abstract. If you can make it an answer, I'd be obliged.
